SSL certificate issues with Docker + Mac + ZScaler
Does anyone know if there's a way to configure Docker Desktop for Mac to recognize the ZScaler Root CA without having to modify individual base images? Right now I keep getting
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
during both container builds and runtime.
Documentation seems to suggest that it should automatically recognize all CAs in the system keychain, but this does not seem to be happening.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454369 seems to suggest it is possible to add this in a persistent manner to the docker VM itself, but I could not find a similar path for MacOS. Any input would really help, thank you!
